# problemas para consumir api con Jquery

Tags: jquery

soy nuevo en esto de la programación web. voy al grano. tengo una api: http://apielviracom20170717104733.azurewebsites.net/api/Menus esta esta creada en azure con asp.net la cual me devuelve un JSON o eso creo e intento consumirlo con este código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul></ul>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "http://apielviracom20170717104733.azurewebsites.net/api/Menus",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {

                $("ul").children().remove();
                $(data).find("MenuCompleto").each( function() {
                    var info = '<li>Fecha: ' + $(this).find("FechaString").text() + '</li>';
                    $("ul").append(info);
                });
             } 
         });

     });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No entiendo porque no funciona, Postman va perfecto, he leído varios post para consumir la api y creo que esta correcto. cualquier ayuda la agradecería mucho.

Gracias, un saludo

Comment: No es Json es un XML

Comment: Cambia en dataType: "json", por dataType: "xml",

Comment: Alguna pista más porfa, ya intente cambiar el datatype y no funciona. Mejor cambio el api y miró de devolver un json o puedo consumir el xml

Comment: voy a poner una respuesta para ver que te devuelve ok?

Comment: Y si pruebas usando fetch?
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch
o en postman puedes ver los detalles del método que se usó para hacer la petición, puedes copiarlos de allí

Answer (score 0):

No estas recibiendo un JSON si no un XML, ahora para leer la informacion del xml:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://apielviracom20170717104733.azurewebsites.net/api/Menus",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {

      $("ul").children().remove();

      //leyendo la informacion del tag 
      let menu = data.getElementsByTagName("MenuCompleto")[0]
      //obteniendo la cantidad de elementos del padre
      let info = menu.children.length;
      //recorriendo los elementos para concatenarlos en la lista
      for (let i = 0; i < info; i++) {
        $('ul').append( menu.children[0].innerHTML )
      }


    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapita respuesta pero no se que problema tengo sigue sin funcionar. Te funciona a ti??

Comment: @aratar79 ya vi mi error, despues del menu, quita `[0]` ya que esta agregado al inicio

Comment: @aratar79 no puedo probar con `ajax` aquí en SOes por problemas de CORS pero abriendo el enlace puedo ver el xml y probar desde ahí, solo así pude hacerlo funcionar

Comment: vaya, pues sigue sin funcionar, he sacado el [0] del GetElementByTagName. No soy capaz de verlo

Answer (score 0):

@JuankGlezz pongo el todo código como ha quedado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul></ul>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://apielviracom20170717104733.azurewebsites.net/api/Menus",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {

            $("ul").children().remove();

            //leyendo la informacion del tag 
            let menu = data.getElementsByTagName("MenuCompleto");
            //obteniendo la cantidad de elementos del padre
            let info = menu[0].children.length;
            //recorriendo los elementos para concatenarlos en la lista
            for (let i = 0; i < info; i++) {
                $('ul').append( menu[0].children[0].innerHTML );
            }


            }
        });

        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

a ver yo aparte de un punto y coma no he visto ningún error, y lo he visto por el [0] que me decías. he estado mirando documentación varia pero no consigo, el concepto lo he pillado a la primera.